# Showing received data objects as a drop down list React Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm new to react and I'm designing a drop down menu which receives its info from an API using axios:

```
axios.get('/api/jobs/list-tags',{headers:headers}).then(respo =>{
      console.log(respo.data)
      this.setState({tagsList:respo.data})
    })
```

this is the shape of the data:

```
Object { id: 1, name: "MongoDB" }
Object { id: 2, name: "JavaScript" }
```

I want to show this data in a drop down list using react-select:

```
<Select placeholder='Select from pre-created Tags 'onChange={handleDropDown('Tags')} defaultValue={values.Tags} required options={this.state.tagsList} />
```

but this doesnt display any item in the drop down list and only shows the blank boxes. how can I actually display the data in a row in the list items? 
like: JavaScript,...

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
   <Select
  placeholder="Select from pre-created Tags "
  onChange={e => handleDropDown(e.target.value)}
  required
  value={this.state.tag}
>
  <options  value=''>Select</options>
  {this.state.tagsList.map(tags => (
    <options key={tags.id} value={tags.name}>
      {tags.name}
    </options>
  ))}
</Select>;
```

and the `handleDropDown` function like

```
  handleDropDown = tag => {
  this.setState({ tag });
};
```

Comment: I don't get an error, it just doesn't show the items in the list

Comment: https://www.positronx.io/react-dropdown-select-tutorial-with-react-select/ this is how the drop down works, I just dont know how to replace the items in that Countries array with the info I receive from the api

Comment: like, instead of  { label: "Albania", value: 355 } I want my { id: 1, name: "MongoDB" }

Comment: you have to put `{ id: 1, name: "MongoDB" } ` these objects in an array and then pass it to the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

`react-select` expects options data in `{value: ..., label: ..., //more fields}` format only.

`label` is displayed on the dropdown options.
(which if needed, can be formatted with the prop `formatOptionLabel`)

and `value` uniquely identifies an option.

with a prop `onChange` you get the whole object back on select. (if losing that is what you are concerned about)

---

Coming back to your example --

`{ id: 1, name: "MongoDB" }`
You can `.map()` on the result array and convert it to any of the below formats:

1. `{value: 1, label: "MongoDB"}`, and in the `onChange` convert back to earlier.
2. `{value: 1, label: "MongoDB", id: 1, name: "MongoDB"}` and omit the `value` & `label` keys-values in `onChange` handler.

Preferably, if the values (here, `id` and `name`) are closely associated then approach 1 should be chosen.